# Could you please check my proof? I need to prove the Hexagonal number formula by induction.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, induction

By construction, we see that the first few Hexagonal numbers are: 1, 6, 15, 28, 45, 66, 91, 153, 190, 231, ....
Then we can see that the recursive formula for the next Hexagonal number will be $4n-3$.
Thus $1+5+9+...+(4n-3)=n(2n-1)$.

By induction, we will show the formula.
For n=3, we have $$(1+5+(4(3)-3)=3(2(3)-1)$$
$$6+9=3(5)$$
$$15=15$$
Thus the statement holds for $n=3$.
Then we assume the statement is true for $n=k$.
So $1+5+9+...+(4k-3)=k(2k-1)$.
Then we will show that it is true for $n=k+1$.
$$1+5+9+...+(4k-3)+(4(k+1)-3)=(k+1)(2(k+1)-1)+(4(k+1)-3)$$
$$=2k^2 +3k+1+4k+4-3$$
$$=2k^2 +7k +2$$

And now this is nonsense. So I know I've done something wrong. I think I set up the equation incorrectly for the induction step? But I'm not quite sure where I went wrong. Proofs have never been my strong point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The induction hypothesis says that$$1+5+9+\cdots+(4k-3)=k(2k-1).\tag1$$So, when you have$$1+5+9+\cdots+(4k-3)+\bigl(4(k+1)-3\bigr),$$you should apply $(1)$, thereby getting$$k(2k-1)+4k+1=2k^2+3k+1,$$which turns out to be equal to $(k+1)\bigl(2(k+1)-1\bigr)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.